# Scheduled/emailed reports using ArcGIS Notebook Server?

Tags: oracle-dbms, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-notebook, scheduler

Is it possible to send **scheduled/emailed reports** via ArcGIS Notebook Server [scheduled tasks](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/notebook/latest/use/windows/prepare-a-notebook-for-automated-execution.htm)?

---

An example of a scheduled report would be:

- The report/task runs weekly
- Emailed to a list of recipients (via an STMP server)
- The report would be emailed out if the resultset/count meets certain conditions (i.e. send the report `if the resultset has >0 records`).

---

*I only have ArcGIS Enterprise 10.7 right now, so it's not possible for me to test this (notebook server scheduled tasks are only available in 10.8 +).*

*A related question here: [Scheduled reports in ArcGIS Enterprise (emailed; condition-based)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395500/scheduled-reports-in-arcgis-enterprise-emailed-condition-based?noredirect=1#comment647670_395500)*

Comment: Did you ever get a solution on this? I am running into issues with hitting an external email server in the AGOL Hosted Notebook.

Comment: @jtmouw Nope, never tried, since I don’t have Notebook Server. Related: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-notebooks-questions/scheduled-emailed-reports-using-arcgis-notebook/m-p/1055208

Comment: @jtmouw I don’t think this will help with your email problem, but you might find it interesting: [2023 Dev Summit - ArcGIS Enterprise: Automation with Hosted Notebooks](https://devsummit2023.esri.com/flow/esri/23epcdev/deveventportal/page/sessions/session/1669767410910001LkuP).

Comment: @jtmouw I get the impression that Esri believes Notebooks are capable of doing this kind of thing. Whenever I say “I want better scheduled/email automation in ArcGIS”, they say Notebooks can do all that. So Esri might be inclined to help you to prove that it works. Have you asked support? Or you could reach out to Jon Emch JEmch@esri.com or someone on the AGOL team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yes" - per your question of can you use Hosted Notebooks to send a scheduled email.

1. Enterprise Notebooks added scheduling at 10.8 as you note. See [Automate notebook execution](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/notebook/latest/administer/windows/automate-notebook-execution.htm) in the Help.
2. Based on form posts, it appears you can have the task send an email. You may run into problems getting proper authentication to an email server. But it seems it can be done. See [notebook example does not work](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-notebooks-questions/notebook-example-does-not-work/m-p/425523) at the Esri Community.
3. Per your specific requirements beyond the question: probably. It's all a matter of the code you write and decisions the code makes on if and who and what to email.